# After system reboot I got Exception handling console input error

Tags: 16.04, java, minecraft, console

Everything worked fine untill I rebooted my PC with Ubuntu 16.04. I noticed that it took longer time to shut down and a bit different text during shut down. After reboot every time I run my jar program I got this error:

```
[10:13:23] [Server console handler/ERROR]: Exception handling console input
java.io.IOException: Resource temporarily unavailable
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:255) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream.read(NonBlockingInputStream.java:169) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-642f6d2-6103339]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream.read(NonBlockingInputStream.java:137) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-642f6d2-6103339]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.NonBlockingInputStream.read(NonBlockingInputStream.java:246) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-642f6d2-6103339]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:261) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-642f6d2-6103339]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.internal.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:198) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-642f6d2-6103339]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.console.ConsoleReader.readCharacter(ConsoleReader.java:2145) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-642f6d2-6103339]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.libs.jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2349) ~[spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-642f6d2-6103339]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_12_R1.DedicatedServer$2.run(DedicatedServer.java:85) [spigot-1.12.2.jar:git-Spigot-642f6d2-6103339]
```

Program runs fine but don't respond to console input. I tried to reload my PC again but problem remained. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the cause of this problem is broken kernel. I tried a workaround (adding --nojline to my arguments in start.sh) and it worked. 
https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/ubuntu-18-04-bad-kernel-update.357871/